# function to draw (canvas) multiple items from an array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

I have a `seat` function which takes a number of values, 3 of which are used to draw circles on the canvas.

each circle is a var named after a person and containing the values from the `seat` function.

I have the following function which I use to draw the individual circles:

```
                ctx.fillPerson = function(p){
                    this.fillStyle = p.fillStyle;
                    this.arc(p.centerX, p.centerY, p.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
                    this.fill();
                }
```

this works great when I do for example, `ctx.fillPerson(johnSmith);` however I am creating multiple groupings of people in array form and I need a function to draw the people in these arrays.

I have an array containing the variables mentioned above like this: `var seatingOne = [johnSmith, joanSmith, bobJohnson, jillJohnson];`

However, I can't seem to get the function right, I feel like I am on the right track, but my limited javascript knowledge is holding me back. So far I have this:

```
            ctx.fillSeats = function(s){
                for ( var i=0; i<s.length; ++i ){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillPerson(indexOf(s));
                }
            }
```

My thinking is that I step through the array and perform a `beginPath();` and `ctx.fillPerson();` for each array item. I THINK(?) `indexOf` if the right tool to use but I am unsure if it is and exactly how to get the desired result.

Any help is much appreciated and please correct me if I said anything improperly (not hip to the all the lingo quite yet either ;) )

Thanks

Comment: I think you want `s[i]` instead of `indexOf(s)`?

Comment: that is probably correct and I made the change but still nothing is being drawn when I use `ctx.fillSeats(myArray);`

Comment: This turned out to be correct, my typo was to blame. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctx.fillPerson(s[i]);

I don't know off the top of my head if you need to end the path each loop.

Comment: I made this change, but it still isn't drawing anything when i use `ctx.fillSeats(myArray);` I know before I started grouping that I could just list the `ctx.fillPerson(myVar);` each with a `ctx.beginPath();` before it and it worked fine.